# Is a file descriptor ever NOT open?

Tags: file-descriptors, open-files, terminology

Of course a file can be open, or not open.

However, a file descriptor by definition refers to an open file (right?).  (Well, except when it refers to something besides a file, like a pipe or what have you.  But it's still open.)

I've encountered the phrase "open file descriptor" several times.  I *believe* this is redundant, and that in fact there is no other kind of file descriptor besides an open file descriptor—but I would like to verify this.

Is a file descriptor ever in any other state besides "open"?  (When it's closed, doesn't it cease to exist?)

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't "open file descript**ion**" you encountered? That is a different concept & term: a file descriptor (number) points at an open file description (record, including offset etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A program executes this:

```
close(0);
```

The standard input file descriptor has not changed value, but it is no longer referencing an open file description.  It is available for re-allocation.  Subsequent attempts to use it in, say, `read()` will result in `EBADF` because whilst *it is still a file descriptor* it is not an allocated one that references an open file description.  It is a *bad* file descriptor.

## Further reading

- ["`close()`"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html).  *The Open Group Base Specifications* Issue 7.  IEEE 1003.1:2008.  The Open Group.  2018.
- ["`read()`"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html).  *The Open Group Base Specifications* Issue 7.  IEEE 1003.1:2008.  The Open Group.  2018.

Comment: "bad file descriptor" is exactly the term I needed, then.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems a very fine distinction, sorry.  Please try not to assume that anyone else will know the same exact definition as you, and make sure any ambiguities can be resolved from context instead.  I can write an answer that agrees with you and appears to disagree with other answers, citing the following:

> Each file descriptor refers to exactly one open file description

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_258

therefore if it does not refer to exactly one *open file description*, it cannot be a *file descriptor*.  Also

> **Once a file is closed, the file descriptor no longer exists**, since the integer corresponding to it no longer refers to a file.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html